# Lines to support selection of cells

Tags: java, jtable, selection, cell

I'm using the Netbeans RCP and want to make cell selection in a jtable more visible.
Therefore I like to draw red lines like the following:

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRRyq.png

I only used GIMP to draw the lines on the screenshot ;-)

When selection increases and more cells are selected, the red lines should be the borders of the selection and should mark the whole width in the columnheader and the whole height in the row header.

My table will be much larger with a fixed columncount of ~35 and undefined count of rows.
Does anyone tried something like this before??

Thanks a lot in advance!
- Michael

Comment: Have you began to mess with the overrided paint function of your custom JTable variation?

Comment: I tried to subclass the ETable to override the paintComponent method, but don't know exactly how. The initComponent is locked for editing by netbeans. I still googled for about 2 weeks, but for the netbeans RCP are not that much examples around. There is a post-creation and post-init for changing the initComponent method, but that seems not what I need for subclassing. I think about moving away from Matisse to get my problem solved...

Comment: Got it to work! Wrote a new class enhancedTable that extends ETable and put eTable = new enhancedTable(); into custom creation code. enhancedTable class simply overrides only paintComponent(Graphics g) {} Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those may direct you to helpful information. Sorry I cannot provide exact answer to your case.

Outline view is a big fat JTable, so basically searching for information on parent components will give you more information on internal things.

`org.openide.explorer.view.OutlineView outlineView;`

**To enable row selection:** 
`outlineView.getOutline().setRowSelectionAllowed(true);`

**To define row selection mode:** `outlineView.getOutline().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);`

**To disable cell selection:** `outlineView.getOutline().setCellSelectionEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thanks! your answer was not the answer, but gave me a hint on how to solve the problem!